# Google Services doesn't work with google DNS

Tags: wireless-networking, router, isp, google-dns

I use DSL at work and home, from the same ISP.

I have the same router with exactly the same model at both locations.

I Have configured the two routers with the very same configuration except the username and the password.

I was using google DNS in both routers.

**now the problem is:**

all google services doesn't work at work with google DNS.

i fixed that problem by switching to the default DNS provided by my ISP or to another public free DNS.

but even after that, i have noticed that videos loading at youtube.com take too long.

And when i or any one of my co-workers try to install any app from google play store it keep telling its downloading for about 15 minutes then it stops without installing anything.

I have contacted my ISP's technical support by Phone and online Chat, i even gave them access to my router by allowing wan access to it, but they don't have any idea.

even after that i took my home router to work, and just changed the username and password, but it still doesn't work.

**Can any one please tell me what is going on?!!!!**

**And how is that even possible?!!!**

Comment: Edit: To solve the problem my ISP just changed the static Public IPs they were giving to me to another ones. unfortunately they didn't tell me what was the problem.